# Jquery FeedEk not loading Posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, rss

I am using FeedEk (https://github.com/enginkizil/FeedEk) js code to load post on my page , (https://www.colonialstock.com/) under the Latest News And Insights, but code is not load anything there.

Any one can Help me to fix this?

https://www.colonialstock.com/ this is a wordpress site.

I need to find why code is not working?? and any error on my code?

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://www.colonialstock.com/js/FeedEk.min.js"
></script>
<script>
  $(window).ready(function () {
    $('#divRss').FeedEk({
      FeedUrl: 'https://blog.colonialstock.com/feed/',
      MaxCount: 6,
      DescCharacterLimit: 90,
      TitleLinkTarget: '_blank',
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="divRss"></div>
```

when I replace "https://jquery-plugins.net/rss" this link code is working.

Comment: Are there any errors reported in your browser's dev-tools _Console_ or _Network_ panels?

Comment: No i did not see any js or other erros.

Comment: Optinly is running
testimonialsSlider.js:66 [Violation] 'message' handler took 388ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 145ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 50ms